# Apple Pay Web - "visa" is not a valid payment network

Tags: applepay, applepayjs, applepay-web

Finding in our logs the following exception:

```
"visa" is not a valid payment network.
```

What's weird is that we added ["visa", "masterCard", "amex", "discover"] as supported networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out we weren't respecting the value returned by `ApplePaySession.canMakePaymentsWithActiveCard()` and not hiding the Apple Pay button accordingly. This error was shown when users hit the Pay button.